# Blender models adding extra faces in Element 3d

Tags: modeling, objects, export, file-format

I modeled a logo in Blender and everything is clean.

[image: model in blender]

When I export an OBJ and import it into Element 3d, a few extra edges have found their way into the model.

[image: model in element 3D]

Any ideas on why this is happening? I have a feeling it's some setting within Element 3d but it could very well be a blender to OBJ issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have quite a few complex ngons in your model. The OBJ exporter may be getting confused. Before exporting to OBJ, in edit mode, select all the faces (or at *least* the ones giving you trouble), and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which is 'triangulate faces'. This will convert all your quads and ngons into triangles.

Once converted, ensure those strange edges have not reappeared (and fix them if they do), then export to OBJ once again.