# How to save as an OBJ and import to Element 3D

Tags: modeling, objects, export

I am trying to create a Ka-Bar knife in Blender. Problem is I cannot figure out how to save the finished product as an .obj file, then import it into Element 3D to use as a 3D object.  I don't even know if I am doing it all correctly in Blender.

Comment: Welcome! Could you be more precise? What's wrong with the Export OBJ command? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll post a quick video of the problem.  I am actually not sure if I am saving it correctly either.

Comment: OK here is the video of where I am stuck lol.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TjH9BU-P7M&feature=youtu.be

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/blender-models-adding-extra-faces-in-element-3d

Comment: As Video Copilot explain, meshes needs triangulation first. From quad to tris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command from the **File** >> **Export menu**

[image]

Or press the spacebar to activate the "Search command" function and start typing his name (**Export OBJ**)

[image]

After that, you will see the file browser where you can choose the exporting folder. On the left, at the bottom of the sidebar there are the **exporting options**.

Comment: Finally got it and exported to Element 3D.  But, I dont think I rendered and saved it correctly.  When I exported it to Element 3D, it came out as a flat object lol.

Comment: Okay here is the new problem and why I think I did not render/save it correctly.  It comes out as a flat object when I import into Element 3D instead of like an actual 3d object. ugggg  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtIeoetmjg8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Do you have the same "flattening" issue if you import it in other 3D software (e.g. Meshlab..)?

Comment: Element 3D is the only 3D program I have. Also, Element 3D is a program for After Effects.  Which you probably already know lol  But could it be because I did not finish the project in Blender correctly???  This is my first project I have done.  I know, no laughing lol

Comment: You can freely pick a copy of Meshlab http://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/ as it is opensource. As far as I see in your videos your project should be correctly exported, that's why it is important to check with another software if the problem occours there too. In my opinion it is more likely that you didn't import it well in Element3D, but without further infomation I would just guess

Comment: Here is another video showing the knife in Blender.  From there I just hit the render then export as an obj.  Am I missing some steps in Blender to make it an actual 3D object?? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pvRryXssok

Comment: No, it looks perfectly nice. Upload your obj and paste here the link, I'll check it  with other softwares for you

Comment: Uhmm, dumb question. How do I upload the obj file???  lol sorry

Comment: You can use Google drive, dropbox, box, filedropper, ... or a site/file hoster of your will, and than paste here the provided link to that file

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=518" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/518/)

Comment: OK got it uploaded!!!  ;)

Comment: Ok, there are a few problems in the geometry (internal faces, n-gons, double vertices...) but nothing that could bring to that "flatness". It is more lokely that you made some mistakes in Element3D. Did you check what is suggested in the FAQ section of this document http://www.videocopilot.net/assets/public/misc/Element_Help_Files.pdf?

Comment: Nope have not seen that. I will check it now.  And thank you very much for the help. And yeah, I am probably going to try and redo the whole project.  WAAAAAy to many mistakes when making like, ie internal faces like you mentioned.  Do you have any suggestions as to how to start out a project like this one?? lol

Comment: Also, what are n-gons, and double vertices??  Sorry, I new again to this lol

Comment: Ok I saved that file and I am going to scrub over everything to make sure I did it correctly next time.  And thank you very much again for your help!!

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!  OMG IT LOOKS AWESOME!!!!